# UIScrollView still receives scroll events underneath a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, events, ipad, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a full-screen UIButton to capture all touch events, so that the scrollView underneath doesn't scroll. However, for some reason, it's not working. Can someone tell me a way to create a view that will capture tap and swipe events so this won't happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just worked it out... The view I was adding it to had a smaller frame than its parent view... So even though the button was big enough to fill the screen, if it's outside the frame rect it won't respond to any touch events.

:)